# Django REST framework. Get object by unique url

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I making rest api of my django project for mobile client.

I have this model and API structure for *Categories* objects:

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Title")
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Url")
```

api/serializers.py

```
class CategoryDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'url'
        ]
```

api/views.py

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategoryDetailSerializer
```

and api/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', CategoryViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='detail'),
]
```

To retrieve *Category* object I use GET request to `my_server_url/api/categories/[pk]/`

Question is how can get object with it's `url` field (which is unique). e.g. like this:
`my_server_url/api/categories/category_1/`
Is it possible with rest-framework?

Or maybe I should get map of [pk]:[url] objects first, then get pk by url from it and pass it to existing request method..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the lookup_field in the view.

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategoryDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'url'
```

You would also need to change the url regex to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<url>[-\w]+)/$', CategoryViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='detail'),
]
```

However i would recommend storing the unique field as a slug field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#slugfield so you assure it is a valid url.